# Internet Explorer 11 doesn't recognize conditional CSS

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I am making myself a little portfolio. On chrome, firefox and opera there is no problem with the footer and making it sticky to the bottom using

```
footer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

However, IE is special and it doesn't work. The easiest fix I could think of was implying `position: relative` only to IE.

So I tried using:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<style type="text/css">
    footer { position: relative; }
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

But my IE doesn't recognize it (also tried to link to `iefooter.css`, no result). However, if I remove the `<!--[if IE]>` all the browsers get the relative position so that must be a problem of IE? My version is the latest I believe - 11.0.9600.16521

The website is here: [www.hrusov.eu](http://hrusov.eu). 
The bugged footer on IE happens on "big" pages such as `About me` or `Projects`

[image: buggedfooter]

Comment: *Oh, that Internet Explorer*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From IE 10 and up IE conditional comments were dropped by Microsoft.

I suggest you rework your CSS that it will work with IE 10 and up.

Answer (score 0):

Position absolute works fine in IE 11. I just tried it. Your code is position:relative, which causes it to display above the bottom. I changed it to position:absolute in the F12 tools, just right click on the target element and select Inspect Element. You can adjust the CSS from there.

I use position:absolute all the time to create fluid, responsive designs and it works great.

Comment: Did you try that on the about or projects pages? Because if you do so you will ejd up with the picture I have posted on the main question

Comment: real quick, I know what you are doing wrong now. You need to make your header and footer position:absolute and your main content scrollable.

Comment: check out the demo site for my latest book, in particular this url in a smaller screen, http://movies.spawebbook.com/#!about. The header and footer a absolutely positioned. The content is vertically scrollable. Inspect the elements in the F12 tools to see how the CSS works. The source code is on my GitHub page, https://github.com/docluv/movies